# How to obtain the luminosity of a blackbody disk?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, radiation, thermal-radiation

How do I get the luminosity of blackbody disk (negligible thickness) with temperature $T$ and radius $r$?

Also how can one obtain the flux density if the object is at a distance $d$ and an inclination angle $\theta$?

Any help at all would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume it to be isothermal then you can use the blackbody radiation formula: it radiates $L=\pi \sigma r^2 T^4$ Watt per side. At a distance $d$ the flux density is $L/4\pi d^2$ Watt per square meter. If it is angled at angle $\theta$ we multiply by $|\cos(\theta)|$. So the flux density received from the disk would be $ \sigma r^2 T^4 |\cos(\theta)| / 4 d^2$.

Actual accretion disks have a temperature profile, so this is just going to be a rough approximation.